# (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*))

Tags: c, malloc, double-pointer

I know that in order to `malloc` an array of pointers to arrays, the syntax should be:

```
(int**)malloc(numberOfDesiredElements*sizeof(int*))
```

Accidentally, I forgot to put the `numberOfDesiredElements*` in front of size. It was messing up my program throwing random segmentation faults, i.e. sometimes the program outputted correctly, sometimes it seg faulted.

Can someone explain what happened when I did not indicate how many slots I wanted?

Thanks!

Comment: The syntax should not be that. Avoid the unnecessary cast.

Comment: `malloc` returns a `void*` which can be converted to `int**` implicitly. The explicit cast _may_ hide an error if you are missing a prototype for malloc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just an ordinary multiplication, not magic syntax; so it allocated space for 1 instead of 3.

Comment: It's multiplication? Oh... T_T What about the random seg faults?

Comment: @Rafcio: if you say `malloc(sizeof(int))`, you get enough memory for exactly one int. If you try to stuff more than one in there, you're in undefined behavior territory - anything can happen. (And use `calloc` to avoid this.)

Comment: If you were assuming you had space for 3 but only had space for 1, you were writing into memory that was used by something else (possibly corrupting a pointer) or maybe to memory that wasn't allocated at all (segfault).

Comment: Right. Thanks, guys! I think I knew that... Maybe I should call it a day :|

Answer (score 3):

A better way of writing it would be

```
int **p = malloc(numberOfDesiredElements * sizeof *p);
```

Cleaner, easier to read, and you don't have to worry about keeping your type straight in the `sizeof` expression.  The cast is unnecessary (in C; it's required in C++, but you shouldn't be using `malloc` in C++), and can suppress a useful diagnostic if you don't have a prototype for `malloc` in scope.

As for what happened when you allocated less space than you intended, well, you went beyond the bounds of defined behavior.  If you clobbered something important, you'd get a runtime error.  If you didn't, your code would *appear* to work correctly.

Comment: +1 for `sizeof *p` ... - allthough regarding readbility I´d prefer `sizeof (*p)`.